# Symfony, twig, date

Tags: date, symfony, twig

Easy question but i could find answer here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

I have this: 
user.birthday|date("Y\m\d")

but the output is to example: 19930224

and i want to separate it buy "/" to example like: 1993/02/24

Any idea? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use backslash  `\` because it is used for escaping characters. You can use `/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the `date()` function, you need to escape `\` with a second one as `\\`.

And as said in the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html):

> To escape words and characters in the date format use \\ in front of
>   each character

So you need to escape it as following in your twig template:

```
{{ user.birthday|date('Y\\\\m\\\\d') }}
```

Comment: Yea, i remember now. I completly forget that "\" is for escaping :P thx